# After implementing the Redis cache in the C# application, test cases start failing in the Azure build pipeline

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

We have implemented Redis cache in the C# application on existing methods like GetMatserData. There is an existing test case that is working fine on the local system after Redis implementation. But on Azure Pipeline we are getting the below error:

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException : It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). Error connecting right now. To allow this multiplexer to continue retrying until it's able to connect, use abortConnect=false in your connection string or AbortOnConnectFail=false; in your code.

Comment: May be the connection string to the redis cache is not provided during the tests? 
Can you provide some code? What excatly are you testing?

Comment: This error occurs at runtime. Are you running the application / integration test during the CI pipeline? I suggest you check your Redis connection string. You may have forgotten the connection string value for an unreachable server (eg localhost)

Comment: I haven't used Redis in Azure but if there are similarities to Azure SQL then you may have to configure it to allow access to other Azure services and/or configure its firewall rules.

Comment: Please confirm that your connection string format looks exactly(!) like this: mycache-cache.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=********,ssl=True,abortConnect=False

Comment: Actually, Pipeline is not able to find the Redis server. Please guide where we need to install and how we can install Redis for the pipeline. So that pipeline finds that and runs the test case successfully.